# Functions and Finding Averages

Tags: python, function, parameters

I started Python last week and this is the question my teacher wants us to solve: Write a function named average_of_3 that accepts three integers as parameters and returns the average of the three integers as a number. For example, the call of average_of_3(4, 7, 13) returns 8.

Functions are very confusing to me but this is what I have so far...

```
def average(num1, num2, num3): 
  avg = (num1) + (num2) + (num3)/3
  return (avg)

num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

I'm not sure if this is right or not... I'm also not sure what to do after this.

Comment: 1) Your function does not have the name required by the assignment. 2) Your function does the calculation wrong (multiplication/division before addition/substraction) 3) You need to call the function with your 3 input values and then do something with the result. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Think of a function as a cook. You give the cook some ingredients and the cook gives you back a delicious dish. When you define the function, you "teach the chef how to cook" by telling Python what ingredients it takes, what it does to the ingredients, and what it gives back.
So you can ask your user what "ingredients they want to give your chef" like so:

```
a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
b = int(input("Enter a number: "))
c = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

But you still need to *give the chef those ingredients*. You do that by *calling* the function like so:

```
answer = average(a, b, c)
```

Side note: The chef can have its own names for the ingredients, so even though you defined them as `a, b, c` while asking the user, when you pass them to the function, the function accesses them as `num1, num2, num3` because that's how the function is defined.

Then you can do whatever you want with `answer`, such as `print(answer)`

Oh, and another thing: remember [PEMDAS / BEDMAS / whatever you call the order of operations in mathematics?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) Such a concept [exists in programming too](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). If you simply do

```
avg = 1 + 2 + 3 / 3
```

You get `avg = 4`. Instead, surround the entire sum in parentheses so that you actually get the average

```
avg = (1 + 2 + 3) / 3
```

Answer (score 1):

this can be done using optional argument or using a list of your values

```
def averaged(*args):
    return sum(args)/len(args)
#or
def averaged1(args: list):
    return sum(args)/len(args)
#------------------------------
print(averaged(3,4,5))

print(averaged1([3,4,5]))
```

```
4.0
4.0
```

you could simply implement this like:

```
num = None
nums = []
while True:
    num = int(input("value: "))
    if num !=0: nums.append(num)
    else: break

def averaged1(args: list):
    return sum(args)/len(args)

print(averaged1(nums))
```

```
value: 1
value: 2
value: 3
value: 0 # <-- breaks here
2.0
```

Comment: correct indeed, but let's not confuse him with *args or lambda

Answer (score 0):

```py
def average_of_3(num1, num2, num3):
  return (num1 + num2 + num3)/3

# call your func
average_of_3(4, 7, 13)
```

You need to pass your numbers as arguments of the function, if you want to see the output use `print()`